# Maven: Plugin to download dependency source from github?

Tags: maven, github, avro

I have a build that depends on `com.odiago.avro:odiago-avro:jar:1.0.5`, which I've been unable to find prebuilt in any repository.

The [source is available on github](https://github.com/wibidata/odiago-avro).  Is there a maven plugin I can use to get maven to download and build the dependency, or will I need to manually download and install it?

Comment: For download step, check out [Maven Download Plugin](https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-download-plugin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such a plugin, but I'd say that even if there were it'd probably serve you better to download the source (using a stable tag), build it yourself, and install it into your local repository (mvn install).  Few reasons:

1. building the 3rd party project is a one-time thing - unless it's something that needs to be repeated as part of your build, there's no gain in having it as part of your maven script.  It'll just slow the build down.
2. the library might change under your feet.

Comment: Probably true.  But to me, the whole purpose of a build tool was so that I wouldn't have to track down and manually install each dependency.  Even having to do only one is a bit of a smell to me, that makes me think less of the software I'm installing.

Comment: True, but don't blame it on the tool in this case. Talk to the creators of `com.odiago.avro` and ask them to provide their artifacts in a public Maven repo. That would be the right way to do it.

Comment: Agreed - there's only so much magic Maven can do, especially for dependencies that aren't on a repo and so aren't really on maven's radar.  Curious about what you're building - if it's internal to your company I would assume that the dependency would have been added to your company's repository, and if it's external, it's a somewhat unusual case for publicly available code to rely on non-standard dependencies (non-standard meaning that they're not provided in any of the usual places maven would look).

Comment: I was building a scoobi app - finally did find a repos with the published artifact (http://nicta.github.com/scoobi/releases/).  Google hadn't been any help, but I found a reference in a build.sbt file.  Agreed on the "there's only so much magic" point.  It was more making me suspicious of the library rather than maven.